# MiniTest is crashing

Tags: ruby, redefinition, ruby-1.9.3

I want to overwite send in Object, like so

```
class Object
    @@object_send = self.instance_method( :send )

    def send *args
        @@object_send.bind( self ).call *args
    end
end
```

or

```
class Object
    def send *args
        __send__ *args
    end
end
```

or

```
class Object
    alias_method :old_send, :send

    def send *args
        old_send *args
    end
end
```

but all this options cause this error to appear

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-2.8.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:871:in `block in process_args': unsupported argument type: Integer (ArgumentError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-2.8.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:862:in `new'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-2.8.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:862:in `process_args'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-2.8.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `_run'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-2.8.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:905:in `run'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-2.8.1/lib/minitest/unit.rb:685:in `block in autorun'
```

Is there anything I can do?

**Update:** Tried updating to 2.9.1 but that hasn't solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a MWE it is difficult for me to analyze your problem. Perhaps I found a first hint for your problem.

I tried to reconstruct the error, but without success:

```
class Object
    alias_method :old_send, :send

    def send *args
        old_send *args
    end
end
n = 5
puts n.send(:*, 2)
```

I get `10`.

But with blocks I get a problem:

```
puts n.send(:times){ |i| p i } #-> #<Enumerator:0xb778a8>
```

With a little modification you can see what happens:

```
class Object
    alias_method :old_send, :send

    def send *args
        puts "send called with #{args}"  #--> [:times]
        old_send *args
    end
end

n = 5
n.send(:times){ |i| p i }
```

You get

```
send called with [:times]
```

The block is missing. You must add the proc-parameter to your redefinition:

```
class Object
    alias_method :old_send, :send

    def send *args, &proc
        old_send *args, &proc
    end
end

n = 5
n.send(:times){ |i| p i } #-> 1 2 3 4 5
```